# Why is my wordpress not able to add new themes or plug-ins? Im missing some features aswell but i dont know why

Tags: wordpress, web, host, web-testing, vs-web-site-project

I have not downloaded Wordpress, im only using a link given to me by the person who was the designer.
Im only logging in with wp-admin.   I have watched tutorial videos on wordpress but still im not seeing the features that are meant to be there according to my research

the Wordpress ver is 5.4.2

please can someone help
thanks

Comment: meybe you don't have admin priviledges

Comment: As Stender says, the designer has only given you limited access - you might be set up as an editor or author for example. There is nothing you can do, you would need to contact the designer to request more access.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress accounts have different roles like admin, editor, etc. The account your designer has given you probably is not admin. Only admins are allowed to add/remove themes and plugins.

Comment: Good day! im using this link :www.*websitename.org*/wp-admin.

Comment: i hope you this will help awnser my question

Comment: This is the link from which you login, but if your account's role is not an admin you cant access the themes and plugins.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I can only deactivate plugins and only have 3 themes (which for some reason dont look like the original). What should do from here in your opinion?

Comment: @someonedev1 As I said in my comment above, the only thing you can do is contact the designer and ask for more access. You can’t do anything about this because you don’t have the privileges.